# Free-ipa - Active Directory seems to be setup, but authentication is not working

Tags: active-directory, authentication, windows-authentication, freeipa

Looking for some troubleshooting help here.

I am trying to be able to authenticate AD users on a Centos7 cluster. For testing this, I am setting up a Windows Server 2012 R2 and the cluster in Azure.

I have carefully followed the instructions here ([Active_Directory_trust_setup](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Active_Directory_trust_setup)) with one modification:

- I believe the dnscmd command as listed does not set up conditional forwarding correctly. I use the Windows GUI and get the correct result. (At least the nslookup and dig commands give the right answers.)

The behavior I have now is:

- ipa trust-show shows the trust
- ipa trustdomain-find finds the one entry
- getent passwd mrtest@ddaddad.internal works and shows correct information
- su mrtest@ddaddad.internal requests a password and returns "Authentication failure"
- ssh of mrtest to the Linux box also fails authentication

I don't know where to look to figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: I still could use help understanding where to look to figure out what is going wrong.  
I did figure out what was wrong in my case. The AD had two IP addresses: one for its NIC and one for the tunnel connecting it to my cluster. I think the problem was that when resolving _ldap._tcp.ad_domain, the NIC IP was returned to the ipa server in the cluster. That IP was inaccessible to the ipa server. Removing the tunnel and connecting the networks made it work.